# Make list from a custom data type in Haskell (reverse operation also)

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm going to learn how to convert a data type to an array using Haskell. That's a case as I need to get that from the data as follows:

```
data List a = Nil | Cons (List a) a
listToList :: List a -> [a]
listToList Nil = []
listToList (Cons Nil a) = [a]
...another pattern match, I guess...
```

What is missing here to complete this conversion without non-exhaustive matching (flatten may be)? I'm embarrassed a few because there is a lack of comprehension how to handle on. Also, I would be grateful for any prompt about a reverse function (from [a] to List a).

Comment: Hint: use an *accumulator*.

Comment: Where is an array here? `[]` is a linked list just like your `List` is.

Comment: Hint: use recursion in the `Cons` case.

Comment: I guess `Cons` here should be named `Snoc`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Only if `last :: List a` is intended to be implemented as `last (Cons _ x) = x`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make of an accumulator here. You define a helper function where you pass a value, and each recursive call, you pass a slighly modified copy of that value.

Your `listToList` thus then will look like:

```
listToList :: List a -> [a]
listToList = go []
    where go … = …
```

Here you still need to implement `go`. `go` has as signature `go :: [a] -> List a -> [a]`. In case you encounter a `Nil`, then you can return the accumulator. In case you encounter a `Cons x y`, you prepend the accumulator with `y` and recurse on `x`.

Comment: I passed "go" a List as a second argument, now it works as needed. A lot of thanks for step-by-step explanation. As to the reverse running, I grasp an obvious solution which turns around calling Cons value constructor throghout a list input.